# Oracle INSERT INTO table of type collection

Tags: oracle

How to I insert data into this table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE COLLECTION_TABLE (id number, collection_object COLLECTION_01
) nested table collection_object store as collection;
```

where `COLLECTION_01` is a type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE COLLECTION_01 AS TABLE OF dept_typ_01;
```

WHERE dept_typ_01 is

```
CREATE TYPE dept_typ_01 AS OBJECT( mgr Person_typ, emps Person_typ);
```

where Person_typ is

```
CREATE TYPE Person_typ_01 AS OBJECT( name CHAR(20),ssn CHAR(12));
```

I tried with empty constructor

```
INSERT INTO COLLECTION_TABLE values (2, COLLECTION_01())
```

which insert only empty data, but when I tried with

```
INSERT INTO 
  COLLECTION_TABLE 
    values (2, COLLECTION_01(
      dept_typ_01( 
        mgr(Person_typ_01 ('name','ssn', 'addr')),
        emps(Person_typ_01 ('name','ssn', 'addr'))
        )
      )
    );
```

`Oracle` is given an exception

```
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "EMPS": invalid identifier
```

Can someone shed some light here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick

```
INSERT INTO 
  COLLECTION_TABLE 
    values (2, COLLECTION_01(
      dept_typ_01(
          (PERSON_TYP ('name1','ssn1', 'addr2')),
          (PERSON_TYP ('name2','ssn2', 'addr2'))
        )
      )
    );
```